# Google Calendar Api Create a 1 Hour Recurring Event Without an EndDate

Tags: rest, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to insert a 1 hour recurring event to my calendar via Rest call:

My question is what to put on the UNTIL and end: datetime if I want the event to not have an recurring end datetime?

```
POST Url: 
www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/[CalendarId].calendar.google.com/events

Headers:
Authorization: Bearer [Access Token],
Accept: application/json,
Cache-Control: no-cache

Request Body: (JSON)

    {
        "description":"Awesome event",
        "end":{
            "dateTime":"**????**",
            "timeZone":"America/Chicago"
         },
        "iCalUID":"e4c76d8b-d32e-414d-9e4e-a22deed4d32f",
        "location":"Office",
        "recurrence":
             ["RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=6;BYDAY=1WE;UNTIL=**?????**"],
        "start":{
            "dateTime":"2016-06-22T14:00:00.000Z",
            "timeZone":"America/Chicago"
         },
         "summary":"Get You Stuff Done"
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried not supplying an End date parameter?

Comment: DalmTo Yeah I receive the error that you must supply an end date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I figured out the way that google would like the structure. To insert a 1 hour recurring with out a recurring end date. Use the following structure.

Request Body: (JSON)

```
{
    "description":"Awesome event",
    "end":{
        "dateTime":**"2016-06-22T15:00:00.000Z",** <-- 1 hour
        "timeZone":"America/Chicago"
     },
    "iCalUID":"e4c76d8b-d32e-414d-9e4e-a22deed4d32f",
    "location":"Office",
    "recurrence":
         ["RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=6;BYDAY=1WE"], <-- Remove UNTIL
    "start":{
        "dateTime":"2016-06-22T14:00:00.000Z",
        "timeZone":"America/Chicago"
     },
     "summary":"Get You Stuff Done"
}
```

Hope this helps someone!